# How do I isolate 3 cores of a quadcore from Linux and use them for Halcon, exclusively?

Tags: linux, halcon

How do I isolate 3 cores of a quadcore from Linux and use them for Halcon, exclusively?

Here is what I've tried so far:

1. I configured Linux to only use core 0 of the quadcore CPU by boot option `isolcpu=1,2,3`
2. I started my multi-thread C++ program and let one thread configure Halcon with a few `HSystem::SetSystem()`. This is the halcon main thread. By default, the "`thread_pool`" option is set to `"true"` (but I also tried `"false"`). And, which is important, at first, this run-function of the halcon main-thread calls `pthread_setaffinity(getpid(), sizeof(set), &set);` for `cpu_set_t set` for which I added core 1, 2 and 3 with `CPU_SET(index, &set)`.
3. Anyway, now a QR matrix code with "Maximum" mode should start several threads on core 1, 2 and 3. But it doesn't work. It only runs on core 1 with almost 90% CPU load, and core 2 and 3 stay at 0% CPU load (seen with `top -H`). This looks to me as if Halcon does miss an magic option to use all 3 cores.

Comment: psrset? (https://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1m/psrset/)

Comment: @Dominique: I need to solve it within the program by API functions since my C++ application also has threads on core 0, but I only want to have its Halcon threads on CPU 1, 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

Are you 100% sure this should run in parallel?
Could you try it with a different code type (ECC200). According to https://www.mvtec.com/products/halcon/documentation/release-notes-1911-0/ in the Speedup section we know for sure the ECC200 reader is parallelized internally by HALCON. If this reader runs in parallel on your system and the QR Code Reader doesn't i would assume the QR Code reader simply isnt parallelized by HALCON.